# convert datetime retrieved from solr to only hours and minutes in django view

Tags: python, django, solr

I am new to **python django** and **solr**, what I am doing in my application is I store closing time as `0000-00-00T01:00:00Z` in solr.
Then I retrieve this data and pass it to a view in the form of a dictionary

```
return render(request, 'searchvenueresults.html',{'query': result['query'],
    'data_set':result['data_set'],
    'data_close':result['data_close'], 
    'exact_found':result['exact_found'], 
    'numFound': result['numFound']
    })
```

so my data_set holds the closing time and I access it as follows:

```
{% for data in data_set %} 
    Closes at <span class="time">{{ data.venue_closing_time }} PM</span>
{% endfor %}
```

when I use this code it displays the closing time as:

```
Closes at 0002-11-30T01:00:00Z PM
```

what I want to display is just :

```
Closes at 01:00 PM
```

I tried

```
{% for data in data_set %} 
Closes at <span class="time">{{ data.venue_closing_time|date:'H:i' }} PM</span>
{% endfor %}
```

but it shows blank value, nothing is displayed.

please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date` template filter will only work if `venue_closing_time` is a `datetime` object. If you just pass it a string (as it seems you are doing) then it will not work. In that case you need to parse the string first, e.g:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime

venue_closing_time = parse_datetime(data['venue_closing_time'])
```

If you pass that to the template, then your date filter will work as expected.

This would be easier if you were using a Solr library that converts the data obtained from Solr into appropriate Python representations in the first place (e.g., pysolr).